# Ms Access Data Macro Return Record Set

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-data-macro

I am using a `Data Macro` for one of my Access table's after insert event. Inside this Data Macro, I am using `SetLocalVar` to call one of my functions written in vba to insert the same inserted record set into my SQL Database. This is how the `Expression` in `SetLocalVar` currently looks like;

```
AfterInsertMacro("TblLotStatus",[LotStatusID], [NextStatus], [Status], [Printed], [Active], [AvailableForPull] )
```

Now, instead of returning back every column as a separate variable, can't I return a record set or a collection or an array etc. ?

Basically I am looking for something like this (written in C# language);

```
AfterInsertMacro("TblLotStatus", new object[]{[LotStatusID], [NextStatus], [Status], [Printed], [Active], [AvailableForPull]} )
```

Or any kind of expression that would look like;

```
AfterInsertMacro("TblLotStatus", [Inserted Recordset])
```

Comment: If it is a macro and/or code in an access form, its **not** VB.Net

Comment: @Plutonix Why cant I use the vb.net syntax to instantiate an array in access ? I thought they were very similar even same in some areas...

Comment: VBA is to VB.Net as *car* is to *carpet*.  They are 2 very different things.  VBA is based on 20-yr old VB6; VB.NET is something entirely different *especially* as to data access

Comment: @Plutonix Okay I removed the tag from the question. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Note that those tags have words associated with them to provide guidance when and where to use and not use them.  Hover over them to see

Comment: AFAIK, in VBA each element of an array must be set by individual reference, with the exception of using Split() function to populate one-dimension array.

Comment: You can certainly pass and return recordsets with VBA - even a function or any by ref params in the sub/function call. The only real limitation here is returning such a data type to a data macro - that's not allowed. However once you jumped into VBA, then why not have VBA do all the work and thus little or no need to return such a recordset anyway? So VBA most certainly allows the passing of a collection, an array, or a recordset (and by ref or by val). However data macros don't support such data types.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I tried sending the primary key, table name and pk colmn name to vba from the data macro so that I can handle getting the record set from vba. However, even I am working on after insert event, vba is not able to find the newly inserted record. Therefore I have to somehow send the values directly from the Data Macro

Comment: @Parfait The first paragraph explains what the data macro is trying to do. Your second question's answer is `Microsoft SQL Server` database. For your third question, you don't need to see my VBA codes to answer my question. I am simply asking how can I return a record set from a data macro to vba.

Comment: You can most certainly pass the new PK id from the after insert macro to a VBA function. However as noted, VBA functions only work when the client is Access (due to it containing VBA). Data macros used from anything else then the Access client don't have use of VBA and VBA is not even assumed to have been installed. If you not using Access as the client, then I see little reason to use the ACE engine and would suggest using SQL server for the data store in this case.

Comment: Just tested  - you are correct, the record is not available outside of the macro until the after insert event is complete.